# Search View not expanding to parent in toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, searchview

am making search functionality into my app. I added search widget into fragment on toolbar but now i want it to expand to maximum with voice search and one more additional button inside search box.

Here how it looks

1. When Fragment starts: Search Icon visible on toolbar with switch button.
2. When tap on search button: SearchView Expand but not complete expand to parent
3. When submit pressed on keyboard: Hide switch button which not working on pressing search button. Only works when submit button pressed.
   [image]

**Here is my code for toolbar menu (SearchView)**

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchmenu,menu);

MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.search_PTL);
searchView=new SearchView(((Navigation_Drawer)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item,MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW|MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item,searchView);
Button voiceSearch=new Button(getActivity());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams navButtonsParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(toolbar.getHeight() * 2 / 3, toolbar.getHeight() * 2 / 3);
voiceSearch.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_access_time_black_24dp));
((LinearLayout)searchView.getChildAt(0)).addView(voiceSearch,navButtonsParams);
((LinearLayout)searchView.getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
// Toolbar.LayoutParams paramsSearch=new Toolbar.LayoutParams(Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
// searchView.setLayoutParams(paramsSearch);

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        switchButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.d(TAG,"Query Text Submit "+query);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Query Text Change "+newText);

        return false;
    }
});
searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        Log.d(TAG,"On Focus Change Listener "+b);
        switchButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search ");
    }
});
searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Search Button On Clicked Pressed");
          // THIS NEVER CALL ON PRESSING OR SUBMIT SEARCH BUTTON

    }
});
}
```

**searchmenu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search_PTL"
        android:title="Search"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/search_toolbar"
        android:icon="@drawable/button_ic_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView">
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/toggle_Button"
        android:title=""
        android:visible="true"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/toggle_button"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

    </item>

</menu>
```

**search_toolbar layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

</SearchView>
```

I want my search view to

1. Expand to parent like google app and gmail app with button inside search box.
2. Need hide switch button as soon as i clicked search button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search_PTL"
      android:title="Search"
      app:actionLayout="@layout/search_toolbar"
      android:icon="@drawable/button_ic_search"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView">
</item>
```

Instead of this:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search_PTL"
        android:title="Search"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/search_toolbar"
        android:icon="@drawable/button_ic_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView">
 </item>
```

Follow these steps.

1. Change this in `onCreateOptionsMenu`

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.searchmenu, menu);

       final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_PTL);
       final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
       searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
       return true;

   }
   ```
2. Implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` to your activity.

Comment: Just tried v7 but same its not expanding to left as you can see in image above

Comment: @androidXP why are your actionLayout to serch view

Comment: check i added search layout to question

Comment: @androidXP you not need to add layout while using `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing out, i removed layout from menu item but still not expending to left and its same as above image.

Comment: If you noticed i am trying in fragment not in activity but i will try luck with your code. Thanks

Comment: let me know if any query @androidXP

Comment: Its same not changing any width but with above code instead of hiding switch button i shift it successfully into drop down menu by implementing `OnActionExpandListener`

Comment: @androidXP xm did you create **searchable.xml** in `res/xml` folder

Comment: what the use of searchable.xml when i am using actionview in menu

Comment: @androidXP please read this from docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Comment: searchble.xml will use when i am performing search in another activity. but as i told you i am doing in fragment.